# Interactable в Unity UI

Tags: c#, unity3d, ui, unity3d-ui

Имеется кнопка UI в которой скрипт *C#* изменяет свойство *Interactable*. При смене свойства с кнопкой всё как надо, но элементы в ней не изменяётся таким же образом как она.

Хочется сделать так, чтобы все элементы в кнопке по изменению свойства *Interactable*(или на крайний случай другим способом)приобретали тот же цвет, что и кнопка. Возможно ли такое, и как это сделать если да, и как иначе достичь такого результата если нет?

**P.S.** На кнопке *Transition* со значением *Color Tint*.

Comment: Т.е. по факту вы хотите: снял галочку Interactable в Unity и все поля Normal Color, Highlighted Color, Pressed Color становились цвета Disabled Color?

Comment: @ThePyzhov Нет, я хочу чтоб все объекты по иерархии находящиеся в этой кнопке приобрели её смойства при disabled и тоже стали прозрачными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, решений тут масса, на самом-то деле. Я бы предложил создать свой кастомный тип кнопки, унаследоваться от кнопки юнити, создать публичный список изменяемых чайлдов и переопределить метод смены состояния. Звучит, возможно, грозно, но делается просто.

Будет примерно так:

```
class CustomeButton : Button
{

    [SerializeField]
    Image[] _childs;        

    protected override void DoStateTransition(SelectionState state, bool instant)
    {
        if (state == SelectionState.Disabled)
        {
            HideChilds(); //Добавляйте прозрачность. Сработает, когда кнопка переключается в Disabled (это как раз при убранном флаге isInteractable)
        }
        else if(currentSelectionState == SelectionState.Disabled)
        {
            ShowChilds(); //Убирайте прозрачность. Сработает, когда кнопка переключается из состояния Disabled.
        }
        base.DoStateTransition(state, instant);
    }

}
```

По идее, будет работать, как нужно)